# Access public static final string in mybatis sql in mapper files

Tags: java, sql, parameters, constants, mybatis

I have a sql written in a MyBatis mapper file which is something like this:

```
<select id="somesql">
   select a,b,c from tbl_name where d = ?
</select>
```

The placeholder value for `d` is supposed to be a constant declared in a file called `Constants.java` as:

```
public static final String d = "d_value";
```

How do I replace the placeholder with the value without actually passing a parameter in the
`<select>` construct? I tried `#{com.pkg.name.Constants.d}` but it didn't work.

**No hard coding!!!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the out of the box behavior of MyBatis, as far as I know, you can't.

You could try to write an [interceptor for the ParameterHandler](http://www.mybatis.org/core/configuration.html#plugins) and inject the value there but this can't always be possible since you can play only with two methods on the parameter handler:

- `getParameterObject` which returns the parameter that was sent to the query (can be a constant, a String, a Map, a custom object or even null as it is the case of your example where you don't send a parameter)
- `setParameters` where I guess you could try to set the parameter if you know where it is on the prepared statement (which most of the times you might not).

My suggestion is to pass it as parameter to your query. The interceptor features of MyBatis are not very well documented, so you might not get the correct working combination from the start and you can end up with more trouble than it's worth.

Answer (score 19):

```
<select id="getConvenienceStoreList" resultType ="Store">
    SELECT * FROM Store
    WHERE type = ${@foo.product.constant.StoreType@CONVENIENCE_STORE}
    ORDER BY id
    LIMIT #{start}, #{limit}
</select>
```

Reference: http://qiita.com/ApplePedlar/items/12dc389cc32f3db5557a

Comment: Actually, this works!! But note that the value is pasted "as is", no escaping, no quotes. So if you do not use it for numbers, you at the very least have to add quotes.

Comment: Actually we are replacing any passed parameters into mappers by this, except the fact, we don't use only STATIC FINAL constants, but also you can directly call some static method, like this: ${@foo.product.constant.StoreType@getWhereClausule()}